# How to add text below shipping methods on checkout

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, shipping

I want to add some shipping policy of company below shipping methods on checkout.
Below is image attached which i want to achieve.
[image]

I am beginner to magento2. Kindly guide me how can i achieve this.
Thanks

Comment: http://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/shipping/shipping-policy-parameters.html
Check this, This is by default functionality in magento 2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rather than any customization you can use OOTB feature of Magento, for that you just need to change your store configurations

```
Store > Configuration > Sales > Shipping Settings > Shipping Policy Parameters
```

[image]

**On frontend It looks like this,**

[image]